# How to represent 2 points on a chart or guage?

Tags: charts, representation

I'd need to display 2 pieces of information very nicely and using a free tool!

Previous Week Score: 85.60%
and
Current Week Score: 96.00%

I can implement this using a MS bar chart but it would be too boring for the client as I've used it on other pages.

What other nice gauges/charts you'd use for this scenario?

Thanks for your thoughts,

Comment: devexpress has so many great gauges but not free: http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Gauges/gallery.xml?page=6